# Количество записей каждого наименования Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

как вывести наименование товара и его общее количество в таблице?
вот такая структура таблицы 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сумму по заказам вы имеете  в виду, или что?

Comment: да, например нужно количество проданного товара "Пальто 99" и сумму

Comment: SELECT `name`, SUM(`count`), SUM(`cost`) FROM `products` GROUP BY `name`

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему перед нами некая таблица деталей заказов клиентов. В простом случае для подсчета количества потребуется запрос вида

```
select name, sum(`count`) as q
from orders
group by name
```

Однако, можно предположить, что поле `name` в таблице представлено для сохранения названия товара именно в том виде, как было при заказе, и что в целом название позиции может изменяться. Аналогично и с ценой, но цена-то логично, что меняется. (а вот поле `cost` при наличии `price` & `count` кажется избыточным, хотя может и учитывать какие-то скидки.)

Поэтому группировку по имени делать нельзя, можем получить разные строки для одного товара с разными названиями. В связи с этим, проще присоединить таблицу товаров и вывести фактическое наименование на текущий момент времени.

```
SELECT p.id, p.name
     , sum(o.count) AS qnt
     , sum(o.cost) AS total
FROM orders as o
LEFT JOIN products AS p ON (p.id = o.product_id)
GRPOUP BY p.id, p.name
ORDER BY p.name
```

в целом данный запрос будет эквивалентен варианту с обратной последовательностью таблиц и внутренним соединением (пересечением) `from products inner join orders`.
Если  же вы хотите видеть полный перечень товаров, с учетом тех, где 0 заказов, то потребуется внешнее соединение `from products left join orders`.